# fitting the good regression for categorical data on R

Tags: r, statistics, regression, data-science

i am quite new on R ! I am a student in econometrics, but still quite new to data science, and i am currently trying to manipulate a dataset and see what interesting facts i can get out of it.  It is mostly on the econometrics part, trying to find an appropriate model, that i am looking for help (i will be happy to receive any kind of advice on any part of my code though, as i am still learning how to use R !).

My dataset is one of employees of a firm, which has levels (hierarchy), and different wages. It is a dataset on one year but i have a similar dataset for each of the previous years and ultimately i would like to group them to work on the evolution of wages in each level.

I started by computing basic statistics on the dataset, following the advice i had been given on a previous post :

```
df%>%
  select(level, sex)%>%
  group_by(level)%>%
  summarise(mean = mean(sex == "F"))
```

And cleaning my dataset :

```
 df <- transform(df, 
                sex=factor(ifelse(sex=="NA", NA, sex)),
                age=as.numeric(age),
                time_passed=as.numeric(time_passed),
                level=factor(ifelse(level=="", NA, level), ordered = TRUE),
                wage=as.numeric(wage))


 summary(df)
```

I plotted age across levels :

```
plot(age ~ level, data=df)

 library(ggplot2)
 ggplot(df, aes(x=level, y=age, fill=sex)) +
   geom_boxplot()
```

I tried to remove the NA, but failed when coding this (it did not remove the NA) :

```
ggplot(df[!is.na(df$level),], aes(x=level, y=age, fill=sex)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

The linear regression showed level as a significant covariate, yet i would like to do it the other way round (level may be explained by age, not the other way round : i but "level" is a categorical variable...)

```
 lm(age ~ level, data=df)
```

I then ran an alternative test for correlation of ranked (ordinal) data, the Spearman rank test, to establish whether there is a significant correlation :

```
 library(pspearman)
 with(df, spearman.test(age, level))
```

I also tried to look at the differences in the mean age for each level (i am telling this so you might see the different things i have tried, i do not really have a pre established workflow so it may seem a bit messy, i am quite new to data science) :

```
(library dplyr)
df %>%
  filter(sex == "F" | sex == "H") %>%
  ggplot(aes(level, age)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~sex) + 
  ggtitle ("age per level, for each sex")
```

I have also tried to follow this workflow, but i think it is limited for my dataset :
https://data.library.virginia.edu/understanding-ordered-factors-in-a-linear-model/

I think a categorical regression model would be nice, i am thinking about a logistic model : i have tried the following method, yet it gives me non significant coefficients which seems wrong (wages are in fact an increasing function of level, which was not rendered by the model plotted then) :
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/regression-with-categorical-variables-in-r-programming/

So you can see how i translated the model in the above article to my dataset, i will put it here :

```
 df$sex = as.factor(df$sex)
 df$level = as.factor(df$level)

 # two-way table of factor variable

 xtabs(~level + age, data = df)

 # partitioning the data
 str(df)

 set.seed(1234)
 data1<-sample(2, nrow(df), 
          replace = T, 
          prob = c(0.6, 0.4))
train<-df[data1 == 1,]
test<-df[data1 == 2,]

# Now build a logistic regression model for our data. glm() function helps us to establish a 
neural network for our data. 


mymodel<-glm(wage ~ age + sex + time_passed + level, 
         data = train, 
         family = 'binomial')
summary(mymodel)
```

So my main question is : what do you recommend to tackle this dataset (i am also grateful for any reading advice, and not afraid to tackle more elaborate models !) ?
Also, i have the same dataset for other years and i wonder if there is a function in R that could enable me to visualise and manipulate the levels over the year (i would like to see if the mean wages for the people in one level evolves throughout the years or not, for example, or the standard deviation).

My dataset has the following structure :

```
structure(list(sex = c("F", "H", "F", "F", "H", "F"), age = c("24", 
"33", "53", "32", "38", "21"), time_passed = c("0", "3", "4", 
"0", "2", "0"), level = c("N7  ", "N7  ", "N9  ", "N7  ", "N8  ", 
"    "), wage = c("2605", "4931", "11123", "3750", "6180", "858,31"
)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I hope i haven't been too long, and thank you in advance for the help you might provide !

Comment: You need to update the original data for removing the NA i.e. `df <- df[!is.na(df$level),]` or else the NA will still remain in the original df when you use it

Comment: You currently have two questions in your question: (1) what's the best way to model this and (2) can you visualize and manipulate a level over years.  The first is an opinion-based question, for which SO is not an appropriate place to ask. However, the second is a code question. I recommend restructuring your question so that it is clear that you are asking for (2) and removing the text for (1), which is more appropriate on the related site CrossValidated https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @akrun i tried to code your line but the NA level still stays in the plot...

Comment: @socialscientist ok, im new to this blog, thanks for the tip, i didn't know stackexchange existed ! ill go post my question there :)